# Finding the Fundamental Group of a generic space X

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

My apologies for the rather unorthodox question. 
I am having some difficulty in finding, as mentioned in the question title, the fundamental group of a generic topological space X. Assume that I know everything in Munkres, Topology 2 ED up to the Seifert-van Kampen theorem (so an undergraduates basic topology course). I understand all the proofs, and the ideas behind them, but am having serious difficulty in methodology in finding the fundamental group given a topological space, and where/how to apply the results studied.

In short, if I have a generic topological space, how would one go about determining its fundamental group? Are there any particular procedures/ideas? How would you go about it? My question is mainly a methodological one.

Thanks to all who reply and I apologise if this is a duplicate, as I can't seem to find an answer to my particular question on the site.

Comment: In general the fundamental group may be quite hard to compute. For example, computing the fundamental group of the [hawaiian earring](https://wildtopology.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/the-hawaiian-earring/), a space whose definition you can certainly understand with just Munkres, requires some fairly advanced algebra.

Comment: In Allen Hatchers book "Algebraic Topology" there are many illustrative exercises about calculating the fundamental group of various spaces. I would suggest that you do a handful of the computational exercises from each of the subsections "basic constructions","Van-Kampens theorem" and "Covering spaces"in the Chapter on fundamental groups. It should be relatively easy to check your solutions using the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Computing the fundamental group of a space $X$ is in general not easy. There are a few  methods which allow you to reduce complexity (for example the Seifert–van Kampen theorem, see the above comments), but you cannot be sure that you will be successful in the end.

However, for a CW-complex $X$ you can us cellular approximation to show that $\pi_1(X) \approx \pi_1(X^{(2)})$, where $X^{(2)}$ is the $2$-skeleton of $X$. This is a substantial simplification.

For finite CW-complexes there exist algorithms to compute $\pi_1(X)$. See for example 
http://hamilton.nuigalway.ie/preprints/FundGrpAlgo-v10.pdf .

For polyhedra (which are special CW-complexes) you get a presentation of the fundamental group (generators come from $1$-simplices and relations from $2$-simplices). See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304481/algorithm-for-computing-fundamental-group-of-simplicial-complexes .
Unfortunately this is not as good as it looks at first glance. Frequently you will not be able to find out which group is described by this presentation, not even if it is trivial or not.

For more general spaces it seems to me that you have to treat them individually. A nice example is the Hawaiian earring as mentioned in Mees de Vries' comment. This is a really hard job.